# Finding all XPaths in a XQuery using Saxon-HE with C#

Tags: c#, xquery, abstract-syntax-tree, saxon, schematron

## Situational Background: XSD with SCH

### XML Schema (XSD)

I have an XML schema definition ("the schema") that includes several other XSDs, all in the same namespace. Some of those import other XSDs from foreign namespaces. All in all, the schema declares several global elements that can be instantiated as XML documents. Let's call them `Global_1`, `Global_2` and `Global_3`.

### Business Rules (SCH)

The schema is augmented by a Schematron file that defines the "business rules". It defines a number of abstract rules, and each abstract rule contains a number of assertions using the data model defined via XSD. For instance:

```xml
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule id="rule_A" abstract="true">
        <sch:assert test="if (abc:a/abc:b = '123') then abc:x/abc:y = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc') else true()" id="A-01">Error message</sch:assert>
        <sch:assert test="not(abc:c = 'abcd' and abc:d = 'zz')" id="A-02">Some other error message</sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
<!-- (...) -->
</sch:pattern>
```

Each abstract rule is extended by one or more non-abstract (concrete) rule that defines a specific context in which the abstract rule's assertions are to be validated. For example:

```xml
<sch:pattern>
    <!-- (...) -->
    <sch:rule context="abc:Global_1/abc:x/abc:y">
        <sch:extends rule="rule_A"/>
    </sch:rule>
    <sch:rule context="abc:Global_2/abc:j//abc:k/abc:l">
        <sch:extends rule="rule_A"/>
    </sch:rule>
    <!-- (...) -->
</sch:pattern>
```

In other words, all the assertions defined within the abstract `rule_A` are being applied to their  specific contexts.

Both "the schema" and "the business rules" are subject to change - my program gets them at run-time and I don't know their content at design-time. The only thing I can safely assume is that there are no endless recursive structures in the schema: There is always one definite leaf node for every type and no type contains itself. Put differently, there are no "infinite loops" possible in the instances.

## The Problem I want To Solve

Basically, I want to **evaluate programmatically if each of the defined rules is correct**. Since correctness can be quite a problematic topic, here by correctness I simply mean: *Each XPath used in a rule (i.e. its context and within the XQueries of its inherited assertions) is "possible", meaning it can exist according to the data model defined in the schema.* If, for instance, a namespace prefix is forgotten (`abc:a/b` instead of `abc:a/abc:b`), this XPath will never return anything other than an empty node set. The same is true if one step in the XPath is accidentally omitted, or spelled wrong, etc. This is obviously not a very strong claim for "correctness" of such a rule, but it'll do for a first step.

## My Approach Towards A Solution For This

At least to me it doesn't seem like a trivial problem to evaluate an XPath (not to speak of the entire XQuery!) designed for the *instance* of a schema against the actual schema, given how it may contain axis steps like `//`, `ancestor::`, `sibling::`, etc. So I decided to construct something I would call a **"maximum instance"**: By recursively iterating through all global elements and their children (and the structure of their respective complex types etc.), I build an XML instance at run-time that contains every possible element and attribute where it would be in the normal instance, but all at once. So every optional element/attribute, every element within a choice block and so on. So, said maximum instance would look something like this:

```xml
<maximumInstance>
    <Global_1>
        <abc:a>
            <abc:b additionalAttribute="some_fixed_value">
                <abc:j/>
                <abc:k/>
                <abc:l/>
            </abc:b>
        </abc:a>
    </Global_1>
    <Global_2>
        <abc:x>
            <abc:y>
                <abc:a/>
                <abc:z>
                    <abc:l/>
                </abc:z>
            </abc:y>
        </abc:x>
    </Global_2>
    <Global_3>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Global_3>
    <!-- ... -->
</maximumInstance>
```

All it takes now is to iterate over all abstract rules: And for every assertion in each abstract rule it must be checked that for every context the respective abstract rule is extended by, every XPath within an assertion results in a non-empty node set when evaluated against the maximum instance.

## Where I'm stuck

I have written a C# (.NET Framework 4.8) program that parses "the schema" into said "maximum instance" (which is an `XDocument` at run-time). It also parses the business rules into a structure that makes it easy to get each abstract rule, its assertions, and the contexts these assertions are to be validated against.

But currently, I only have each complete XQuery (just like they are in the Schematron file) which effectively creates an assertion. But I actually need to **break the XQuery down into its components** (I guess I'd need the abstract syntax tree) **so that I would have all individual XPaths**. For instance, when given the XQuery `if (abc:a/abc:b = '123') then abc:x/abc:y = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc') else true()`, I would need to retrieve `abc:a/abc:b` and `abc:x/abc:y`.

I assume that this could be done using Saxon-HE (or maybe another Parser/Compiler currently available for C# I don't know about). Unfortunately, I have yet to understand how to make use of Saxon well enough to even find at least a valid starting point for what I want to achieve. I've been trying to use the abstract syntax tree (so I can access the respective XPaths in the XQuery) seemingly accessible via `XQueryExecutable`:

```cs
Processor processor = new Processor();
XQueryCompiler xqueryCompiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
XQueryExecutable exe = xqueryCompiler.Compile(xquery);
var AST = exe.getUnderlyingCompiledQuery();

var st = new XDocument();
st.Add(new XElement("root"));
XdmNode node = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(st.CreateReader());            
AST.explain((node); // <-- this is an error!
```

But that doesn't get me anywhere: I don't find any properties exposed I could work with? And while VS offers me to use `AST.explain(...)` (which seems promising), I'm unable to figure out what to parametrize here. I tried using a XdmNode which I thought would be a `Destination`? But also, I am using Saxon 10 (via NuGet), while Destination seems to be from Saxon 9: `net.sf.saxon.s9api.Destination`?!

Does anybody who was kind enough to read through all of this have any advice for me on how to tackle this? :-) Or, maybe there's a better way to solve my problem I haven't thought of - I'm also grateful for suggestions.

## TL;DR

Sorry for the wall of text! In short: I have Schematron rules that augment an XML schema with business logic. To evaluate *these rules* (not: validate instances against the rules!) without actual XML instances, **I need to break down the XQueries which make up the Schematron's assertions into their components so that I can handle all XPaths used in them. I think it can be done with Saxon-HE, but my knowledge is too limited to even understand what a good starting point what be for that.** I'm also open for suggestions regarding a possibly better approach to solve my actual problem (as described in detail above).

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While XQueryX (as pointed out by Michael Kay) would theoretically have been exactly what I was looking for, unfortunately I could not find anything useful regarding an implementation for .NET during my research.

So I eventually solved the whole thing by **creating my own parser** using the [XPath3.1 grammar for ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) as an ideal starting point. This way, I am now able to retrieve a syntax tree of any Schematron rule expression, allowing me to extract each contained XPath expression (and its sub expressions) separately.

Note that another stumbling block has been the fact that .NET still (!) only handles XPath 1.0 genuinely: While my parser does everything as supposed to, for some of the found expressions .NET gave me "illegal token" errors when trying to evaluate them. Installing the [XPath2 NuGet package by Chertkov/Heyenrath](https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net) was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If this were an XSD schema rather than a Schematron schema, then Saxon-EE would do the job for you automatically: this is very similar what a schema-aware XQuery processor attempts to do. But another difference is that in schema-aware XQuery, you can't assume that every element named `foo` is a valid instance of the element declaration named `foo` in the schema; it's quite legitimate, for example, for a query to transform valid instances into invalid instances, or vice versa. The input and output, after all, might conform to different schemas.

Saxon uses path analysis to do this: it looks at path expressions to see "where they might lead". Path analysis is also used to assess streamability, and to support document projection (building a trimmed-down tree representation of the source document that leaves out the parts that the query cannot reach). The path analysis in Saxon is by no means complete, for example it doesn't attempt to handle recursive functions. Although all these operations require Saxon-EE, the basic path analysis code is actually present in Saxon-HE, but I would offer no guarantee that it works for any purpose other than those described.

You're basically right that this is a tough problem you've set yourself, and I wish you luck with it.

Another approach you could adopt that wouldn't involve grovelling around the Saxon internals is to convert the XQuery to XQueryX, which is an XML representation of the parse tree, and then inspect the XQueryX (presumably using XQuery) to find the parts you need.

Comment: Uh-oh, I'm not sure if I should feel encouraged or hopeless by the statement "tough problem, good luck with that" - coming from Michael Kay, haha :-)

While I do have access to Saxon-EE (because I am an Oxygen user), regarding .NET I unfortunately am stuck with HE for now.

Comment: I have edited the question and (at "Where I'm stuck") added some code regarding my attempt to get an abstract syntax tree of an XQuery using `XQueryExecutable.getUnderlyingCompiledQuery()`.

Comment: Added the suggestion of using an XQueryX representation of the query.

Comment: Wow, thanks again, Michael! That's the first time I've heard of XQueryX and this might be - _deus ex machina!_ - indeed just what I need. I'll look into it!